# How to change paths and URLs in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I am very new to Jekyll and I am failing to find configuration to change the following:

1. I built a basic Jekyll site using `jekyll new .` and ran `jekyll serve` to learn and built a layout using Jekyll. The basic test site gives me the following URL for posts: `/jekyll/update/2016/01/30/welcome-to-jekyll.html`. Is the URL like that because I am running `jekyll serve` and not `jekyll build`? I want to remove the the jekyll/update from the URL path, so my final URLs for posts look like the following: `/2016/01/30/welcome-to-jekyll.html`.
2. I want my pages to be stored in a separate directory `_pages` instead of the root directory. How can I do that?
3. Is there way to prepend a path to files loaded from a specific directory? For example, I want to make a /_projects directory. Then add files with the following permalinks: /prj-test1, /prj-test2, /prj-test3. When compiled, I want to get the following URLs: /projects/prj-test1, /projects/prj-test2, /projects/prj-test3, respectively. Is this possible?

Comment: Everything is in jekyll documentation http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, everything you asked is possible.

1. Take a look at [these examples](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#permalink-style-examples), you might want to choose one of them. But to do as you asked, you'll need to change the permalink to `/:year/:month/:day/:title.html`. To do that, add this line to your `_config.yml` file:

   `permalink: /:year/:month/:day/:title.html`
2. It depends on the structure you want to achieve. You can use [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) or simply create [pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/) inside a folder called `pages` (without the underscore).
3. Yes. You can do that via [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/), for example.

I recommend you to take a look at some templates, so you can see how the code works in different ways:

- Try some Jekyll Themes [here](http://jekyllthemes.io/) and [here](http://jekyllthemes.org/). Download them and study their structures.
- If you want to go deep, take a look how Jekyll build [its own website](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll).

Hope to have helped!